# Generating my own arbitrary polynomials in Julia

Tags: julia

I have a problem where I need to generate my own monomial sequence of N terms and evaluate it numerically - a polynomial basis, mind you.

What I need is a **function** that I can **generate**. The problem is that (as far as I know) I can't iterate over a function I have already defined in order to keep adding terms of my own devising (the monomials), which is what I want. The only way I know how to add the terms that I want is *manually*, but that won't do.

Basically, I want something like...

```
N=4
#Code runs, and then I get something like the following:
f(x) = x^0 + c1*x + c2*x^2 + c3*x^3 + c4*x^4
```

And I want it to be a function that can be evaluated or differentiated via other packages.

Note: I want to operate on the coefficients in order to see if I can solve a problem where I assume the polynomial is the solution that I then have to optimize.

Yes, I know the package **Polynomials.jl** can tackle the aforementioned example quite readily and cleanly, but what I want is to be able to define each of the terms that I keep adding to the polynomial sequence myself, make them a trigonimetric function, an exponential, etc. Maybe I want to define the Fourier series, or whatever. I want to build my own polynomial base that I can then evaluate.

Like this:

```
N=4
#Code runs, and then I get the following:
f(x) = x^0 + c1*cos(x) + c2*sin(x) + c3*exp(3*x) + c4*x^4
```

I tried with Symbolics.jl, played with Polynomials.jl, tried to get it done with varargs, and nothing worked. I am genuinely stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated, even if just to tell me *"Go learn metaprogramming,"* or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and finally found a nice solution.

```
function polyconstruct(order)
     # construct polynomial expression
     expression = join([i<order ? "p[$i]*t.^($order-$i) .+" : "p[$i]" for i in 1:order])

     # define function
     eval(Meta.parse(join(["m(t,p) = ",expression])))
end
```

then in repl:

```
julia> polyconstruct(5)
    m (generic function with 1 method)
```

and to confirm that it works:

```
julia> m(2, [1,0,0,0,0])
    16
```

**Explainer**

Overall logic is to construct strings of each polynomial order in a list comprehension. I used the `cond ? true : false` to differentiate the last 0th order where there's no `+` operation following, and finally joined all strings together to create the polynomial expression.

Then on the function definition, the same logic follows. The function declaration is joined with the polynomial expression, the entire string is parsed to convert to expression and finally evaluated.

In summary this function defines the following polynomial function of order `n`:

`m(t,p) = p[1]t^(n-1) + p[2]t^(n-2) + ... + p[n]t^0`

where `p` is a vector of length `n` containing `[p[1], p[2],...,p[n]]`.

Comment: It's not generally considered a good idea to do metaprogramming with strings. In this case, everything is evaluated in global scope. Also, no matter what you do, your function is called `m`, I cannot do `p = polyconstruct(5)` and then call it as `p(...)`. Instead, you should return an anonymous function. For example: `mypoly(c) = x -> sum(c[i]*x^(i-1) for i in 1:length(c))`. Or better yet, `mypoly(c) = x->evalpoly(x, c)`. In fact, in your particular example, just use `evalpoly` directly. You very rarely need metaprogramming, and you shouldn't do it with strings.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help or at least gives you an insight:

```
julia> function myf(x, coefs)
           myExpressions = [x^0, cos(x), sin(x), exp(3*x), x^4]
           @assert length(coefs) == length(myExpressions) "The length of coefficients doesn't match the length of the expressions."
           return coefs*myExpressions
       end

julia> myf(1, [1 2 3 4 5])
1-element Vector{Float64}:
 89.94716525891064

julia> myf(1, [1 2 3 4])
ERROR: AssertionError: The length of coefficients doesn't match the length of the expressions.
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you so much for answering. Yes, that works if I want to evaluate it... unfortunately it returns an evaluated function and not something that can be later differentiated... but at least it does take care of one aspect of the issue which was devising my own basis to then evaluate it. I'll have to figure out the differentiation part later, probably calculate the specific use case analytically and then hardwiring it to code later.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
mypoly(coeffs, funs) = x -> sum(c*f(x) for (c, f) in zip(coeffs, funs))
```

Then construction and call is like this:

```
julia> p = mypoly((1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (x->x, cos, sin, x->exp(3x), x->x^4));

julia> p(1.5)
390.01498456523484
```

For ordinary polynomials, you should use the `evalpoly` function. And always remember that anonymous functions/lambdas are very powerful and convenient.